# measurability of a set in the product space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M)$ and $(Y,N)$ be a measurable space. Then, the product sigma algebra $K$ on the product space $X \times Y$ is defined as the sigma algebra generated by the set $\{A \times B \mid A \in M, B \in N \}$.

Let $C \not \in M$ and $D \in N$. Then, since the sigma algebra is generated by the cartesian products of measurable sets, it seems that we must have $C \times D \not \in K$, but how do I prove this?

Comment: For example [like here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2027480).

Answer (score 0):

Notation: $[A]^{\leq \omega}$ is the set of countable subsets of $A$ (for any set $A$).

(1). (i).Let $S_0$ be the Boolean algebra generated by $\{c\times d: c\in M\land d\in N\}.$

For ordinal $x<\omega_1$ let $S_{x+1}$ be the Boolean algebra generated by $[S_x]^{\leq \omega}.$

For countable limit ordinal $x\ne 0$ let $S_x$ be the Boolean algebra generated by $\cup_{y<x}S_y.$

(1). (ii). Let $K^* =  \cup_{x<\omega_1}S_x.$ Then $K^*$ is a Boolean algebra and we  must have $K\supset K^*.$

But $K^*$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For if $T\in [K^*]^{\leq \omega}$ then for each $t\in T$ let $x(t)$  be the least $x<\omega_1$ such that $t\in S_{x}.$ Let $y= \sup_{t\in T}x(t).$ Then $y<\omega_1$ and  $T\in [S_y]^{\leq  \omega}$ so $\cup T\in S_{y+1}\subset K^*.$

So $K^*=K,$ by def'n of K.

(2). Let $p_1$ be the projection of $X\times Y$ onto  $X.$ Now prove, that for any $x<\omega_1,$  the assertion  $$\forall y<x \;\forall t\in S_y\;(p_1(t)\in M) $$ $$ \text { implies}\quad  \forall t\in S_x\; (p_1(t)\in M).$$ By transfinite induction and the def'n of $K^*$ we obtain $\forall t\in K^*\;(p_1(t)\in M).$